# How can I delete every cell with a specific value in excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to delete every zeros in a worksheet.

The zeros are spread out random in my worksheet.

How can I easily delete the zero cells with VBA?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I'm sure you are aware, both number formatting and Excel Options, Advanced, Display options for this worksheet, Show a zero in cells that have zero value can halt the display of zeroes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code to remove zeros in active sheet:

```
Sub RemoveZeros()

Dim Rng As Range

For Each Rng In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  If Rng.Value2 = 0 Then Rng.ClearContents
Next Rng

End Sub
```

Comment: This is the less efficent answer.

Comment: @AnonymousType But it truly deletes the zeros. The other one replaces the zeros in other numbers too.

Comment: @kanbhold not sure if that is correct. Dan is using lookat parameter

Comment: Why do you use .Value2? What is the difference?

Answer (score 5):

This will replace all zeros with nothing:

```
Sub ZeroToBlank()
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Replace 0, "", lookat:=xlWhole
End Sub
```

Updated as per comments from Jeeped. Nice catch Jeeped.

Comment: is either better in large usedRanges? replace versus For Each? I'd imagine Replace is better but maybe not.

Comment: The one with the for each will do it cell by cell BUT will clear the contents, Mine will do it all in one go but will not really clear it, it sets the cell contents to "", whilst this is nothing it is not a true clear contents. Which is the best match is up to you and your need. Most of the time I would go with mine due to simplicity and time but the first code posted is probably a "better" way to do it. You can chop mine down further by replacing activesheet.usedrange to Cells

Comment: Note: as you have stipulated a large dataset, the for each method could take some time over the replace method.

Comment: What does the lookat thing mean?

Comment: @kanbhold - This routine in directly analogous to using Find & Replace (Ctrl+H) on a worksheet. In fact, it uses the 'remembered' settings from the last user-driven F&R. The `lookat:=xlWhole` is the same as the *Match entire cell contents* option. It makes sure you are not turning *9001* into *91*.

Answer (score 3):

You might try,

```
sub hide_Zeroes
    ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False
end sub
```

While this does not actually clear the zero values, it removes them from view. It also hides zeroes that are the result of formulas while not removing the formulas.